# Auto sizing images within a div

Tags: html, css, image

So I'm building this custom admin panel for users to easily build out there own web site data into a collection of templates. The main problem I am running in to is dealing with images. There is a div on one template that is 380px by 150px. My question is:

Is there a way to auto resize an image to fit in the div and to also not have it stretch or clip? I am open to all solutions but if it works in IE that would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about setting the image's width and letting the browser to set it's height proportionally?

Comment: How can you not have stretching or clipping if you allow div to resize  without maintaining the aspect ratio?

Comment: With plain css, no. You'd need to know the sizes of the containing box and target image, and set appropriate sizes on the image. This means using Javascript to do the calculations and change the image's css appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

Yes that would be :

```
#your_div.div{
    width:380px;
    height:150px;
}
#your_div img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

The image may be resized but not distorted, and you may also have some "blank" space left somewhere but that's logically expected.

Comment: Ok well... to whom has given that answer a -1, can you please explain? Because i'm using this code in a website and it works very well.

Comment: accidentally clicked -1, meant to click +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to accomplish this. If the images are being added dynamically (on the fly), you could leverage .live() ...

```
$('.someDivClass').children('img').live(function(){

var desiredWidth = /* your own logic here */;
$(this).width(desiredWidth);

});
```

Alternatively, you could just target the height of the image as well (or both).